# Is there a better word/phrase/idiom for "talking too much but not doing anything"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

This is the sentence I made which undoubtedly looks wordy in my opinion.

> A: No, that's wrong! Be careful with the fire! You're going to burn
> them all!
>
> B: Do it right know then! Don't just **talk too much without doing
> anything**.

I hope you get the situation. I need to substitute the terms in bold with a single word or an idiom, is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent is to show frustration with the person talking so much, this expression or similar fit:

> Get out and push, or shut up.

This refers to a situation where someone sitting in a car is yelling corrective instructions to someone pushing that car.

Comment: @user516076 I appreciate the quick check mark, but since this question is so new, you might want to take it back so other people will be encouraged to answer. With word request questions, you often get a lot of high quality answers. I think mine are good, but there might be better ones coming. Also, people might think my answer is bad and downvote it, which is important to consider

Comment: no it's fine, in fact I like the last part, "or shut up"

Answer (score 1):

The closest expressions I can think of that match those words are:

> If you're so smart, ...
> If you know so much, ...
> If you can do it better, ...

and

> ... why don't you do it?
> ... come and do it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Another common phrase to describe this is **all talk and no actiion.** For example:

> Do it right now then, unless you're all talk and no action.